# Utilising Javassist to provide overloading based on return type

Tags: java, javassist

I've used Javassist to dynamically change the return type of a function call, but it's not working.

I've got a call that is defined in the source code as simply:

```
Boolean getResult(){return true;}
```

But then at run time I dynamically change it to:

```
String getResult(){return "true"}
```

I then call it as:

```
Object o = myobject.getResult();
```

And get a MethodNotFound exception. If I use reflection I can see my new method on the object, but the call is failing, apparently because it's somehow bound to the old return type.

If I call the new method reflectively (pseudocode):

```
Method m = myobject.getClass.GetDeclaredMethods().(...find method named GetResult...)

Object o = m.invoke(myObject);
```

Then all works fine, and I can switch between manipulated and non-manipulated byte code without issue, and I can see that the type of O is either String or Boolean accordingly.

Any ideas why?